# How to build scichart charts in iOS project (Xamarin Form)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, .net-standard-2.0, scichart

I need to build an application with xamarin forms that will be compatible for iPAD air 2, which will have a series of forms to register information, which must then be displayed in reports that include a mix of tables, traffic lights (images) and charts(which are complex To create what I will use scichart that supports line chart, errorbar, bars, points), I will have to hire xamarin ios (which is almost finished), but I doubt it is what I will call such components that will be generated on a screen defined in the shared project (xaml), and mix it with the graphics widget where scichart references will be in the xamarin ios project

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akcn6.png)

Comment: https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Xamarin.Examples

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYdab-0XHMA&feature=youtu.be

Check the above links.

Comment: yeah but not is the same kind of project what i need :( I'm using xamarin forms not with PCL, please see this example of screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akcn6.png